# Deleting a entity with a one to many. (DbContext)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

The foreach does not delete anything.. it only seems to NULL some fields in the table.. .. and how I delete the main parent after that Im not sure... been looking around for a simple solution with no luck..

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        tMember mem = db.tMembers.Find(id);

        // find all VoteScores related to the member and delete them
        var voteScores = db.tMemVoteScores.Where(mvs => mvs.MembersID == mem.MembersID).AsEnumerable();

        foreach (var mvs in voteScores)
        {
            var singleMvs = mvs;
            mem.tMemVoteScores.Remove(singleMvs);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        //Delete the actual member now... where is the remove method?  
       // mem.remove???




        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove calls in Entity Framework need to be done at the DbSet level, and not on the individual items found in a list. This would also need to be done for the parent object itself, i.e. the following:

```
foreach (var mvs in voteScores)
{
  var singleMvs = mvs;
  db.tMemVoteScores.Remove(singleMvs);
}

db.tMembers.Remove(mem);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tMember mem = db.tMembers.Find(id);
db.Entry(mem).State = EntityState.Deleted;
db.SaveChanges();
```

How about this?